# Need help naming a class which represents a value and its linear variation

Tags: naming-conventions, naming

While doing some refactoring I've found that I'm quite often using a pair or floats to represent an initial value and how much this value linearly varies over time. I want to create a struct to hold both fields but I just can't find the right name for it.

It should look something like this:

```
struct XXX
{
    float Value;
    float Slope; // or Delta? or Variation? 
}
```

Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: Good question, I have often found naming to be paramount. You can be stuck on a problem, and then think about naming, when you get the naming right, the problem goes away!

Comment: Agree. IMO, correct naming in general has to be one of the most difficult tasks for a programmer. Finding the correct name means full understanding of both the problem and the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have an initial value, and a value indicating how 'something' evolves, you could go with something like "Linear Function".

I would also add the necessary member functions:

```
struct LinearFunction {
    float constant;
    float slope;
    float increment( float delta ) const { return constant + delta*slope; }
    void add( const LinearFunction& other ) { constant += other.constant; slope += other.slope; }
    LinearFunction invert() const { 
        LinearFunction inv = { -constant/slope, 1./slope; };
        return inv;
    }
};
```

Or am I to eager here?

Comment: Sorry for the silly question but, why call it 'function' if it just represents the data that will be used by the function?

Comment: After thinking a bit about it I think this is the perfect solution for my needs, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I guess i would prefer this kind of naming:

```
struct ValueDeltaDuplet
{
    float Value;
    float Delta;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Initial value + constant slope : isn't this an affine function ?

Answer (score 1):

Feels like a "Scale" to me...

```
struct ValueScale
{
    float Value;
    float Slope;
}
```

or maybe

```
struct ScalableValue
{
    float Value;
    float Slope;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's like [Arithmetic progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) (or arithmetic sequence)

```
struct sequence_num_t {
    float value;
    float delta;
};
```

or

```
struct SequencePoint
{
   float Value;
   float Delta;
};
```

Comment: +1 I liked the link to the mathematical concept behind. I just need a 'cool' and easy name for it :)

Comment: Ok :) What about the 2nd name?

Comment: Well, I don't want clients of this class to assume it's either a point or a sequence. I want it to have a more abstract name (but not as loose as FloatPair)

Answer (score 0):

```
struct ValueSlopePair
{
    float Value;
    float Slope;    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
struct FloatPair
{
    float Value;
    float Slope;    
}
```